# What is the sampling design and how to declare it in the survey()

Tags: r, sampling, survey

I have a sample design that can be resumed in:

1. Split the city in X areas and, for each area, sample 5% of the residences and get some informations about it;
2. For each residence, interview ALL residents;
3. In the end, weights to homes and residents are calculated.

So, actually, I have 2 samples: one for residences and another for residents. My question is: what are the sampling designs and how declare it on survey()?

Each dataset has this variables:
CD_APONDE - A code to identify the splited areas
V0300 - A code to identify the residences
V0010 - The weight

The first one (for the residences), I believe that is a stratified sampling and should declare like `svydesign(strata = ~ CD_APONDE, weights = ~ V0010, data = dados)`.

The second (for residents, and my true question) I guess that is a stratified 1 - level Cluster Sampling design, but have not sure, and should use `svydesign(ids = ~ V0300,  strata = ~ CD_APONDE, weights = ~ V0010, data = dados)`.

Am I right? Wrong? 50/50?

Comment: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/svy_howtochoose.htm might help

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyDamico, but my problem isn't only in `survey()`, but is also in identify the sample design correctly. I know that in all cases the pontual estimation will be the same (at least, for the many I tried), but I'm also interested in the standard error estimation.